Angular SSR handle dynamic meta tags
I want to create meta tags based on a configuration that I have in the assets of my page. The idea is to use Angulars SSR feature to prerender the page with those meta tags in place.
I am currently unable to make this work and do not understand how this is supposed to work, so any help
would be really appreciated!
I tried to create a Service for the SEO.
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SeoService {
  constructor(private readonly title: Title, private readonly meta: Meta) {}

  updateTitle(title: string): void {
    this.title.setTitle(title);
  }

  updateDescription(description: string): void {
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: description });
  }

  ...
}

Then I use this Service in my components OnInit function to populate it:
@Component({
  selector: 'stars-defered-blog-post',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [BlogPostComponent, LoadingComponent, AsyncPipe],
  templateUrl: './defered-blog-post.component.html',
  styleUrl: './defered-blog-post.component.scss',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class DeferedBlogPostComponent implements OnInit {
  post: PostData;

  constructor(
    public readonly loadingService: LoadingService,
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly blogPostDataClientService: BlogPostDataClientService,
    private readonly seo: SeoService
  ) {
    // Get current route and get the post id from the route
    const route = this.router.url.split('/');
    // Get the last element of the route array and remove the fragment if it exists
    const routeId = route[route.length - 1].split('#')[0];

    // Get the post data from the service
    this.blogPostDataClientService.getBlogPostData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.post =
        data.find((post) => post.route === routeId) || NOT_FOUND_BLOG_POST;
      if (!this.post.published) {
        this.post = NOT_FOUND_BLOG_POST;
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.seo.updateTitle(this.post.title);
    this.seo.updateDescription(this.post.description);
    // add other tags...
  }
}

